# asp.net mvc 5 stack overflow exception when html.render() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a controller with following action. Passing list of categories using viewdata as below

```
 public ActionResult Home()
        {
            ViewData["categories"] = db.Categories.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

I want to render the list of categories using partial view.
so partial view is created with following markup

```
@using test.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "mnuCategories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Browse Categories</h2>

@foreach(Category c in (IEnumerable<Category>)ViewData["categories"])
{
    @c.CategoryName
}
```

i am rendering this partial view on home page using

```
@Html.Partial("mnuCategories")
```

but when i am running the application it given me "stackoverflow excception"

Comment: Post the full exception message you're getting. Also, your partial view does not need to include the Layout again (or even set the Title again). The calling view will take care of that. Try removing `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Comment: thank you so much Brandon...removed ."Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" and it worked....

Comment: good to hear. I've posted the same comment as an answer. You can select it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial view does not need to include the Layout again (or even set the Title again). The calling view will take care of that.

Remove this block

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "mnuCategories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```